# Converting an FSA to a regular expression

Tags: regex, finite-automata

This morning I created an FSA that is designed to verify the local part of an email. To simplify these things for myself I made these specifications

'The local part of an email address must use any of; uppercase A-Z and lowercase a-z alphabet letters, digits 0-9, ‘+’ and dot ‘.’, provided it does not appear consecutively. The local part must not start or end with either ‘+’ or dot ‘.’
'

[Local Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYpHT.png)

I am happy that this covers the requirements I made, however, I am having trouble converting it to a regular expression. It obviously begins with,
^[A-Za-z0-9] and ends in @$, but after that, I am not sure how to structure it.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it as three different states. You need to start with one or more `[A-Za-z0-9]`, then optionally a single dot or plus, then jump back to the start state, and finally accept on a @.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+([.+][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@
```

This isn't actually a very good specification; it disallows many valid email addresses. You should refer to the actual definition in [RFC5222](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html) instead.

Comment: This is much cleaner, thank you. My task given preferably wants it to be simplified (from high school), but I think knowing that I can simplify this more I will try a more holistic regex.

Comment: `^[\w\d]+([+.][\w\d]+)*@$`

Comment: @Piterden That still fails to allow dashes, and some other less common but technically perfectly valid characters. Depending on the platform, `\w` may also be locale-dependent, which could be bad or good, depending on what precisely you are hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

With negative lookahead (to check consequent `.`):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?!.*\.\..*)[A-Za-z0-9+.]*[A-Za-z0-9]@$
```

Comment: Using some test cases I noticed your expression allows the local part to end in '.' and '+'. https://regex101.com/r/MxMMeq/4 The negative lookahead is something I haven't seen before though, so thanks for that.

Comment: Just one more question if you don't mind, how can I check that this regular expression and my FSA are equivalent?

Comment: @Okeh, tests? :) unit-testing for example, mb there are some automation-testing frameworks/tools to achieve this. Honestly I know nothing about FSA...

Comment: Ok no worries. I'm gonna try to learn how to reduce properly but otherwise I'll use your one.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it is working if i understand you correctly

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9+.]+@$
```

https://regex101.com/r/MxMMeq/1

```
^[\w\d]+([+.][\w\d]+)*@$
```

https://regex101.com/r/MxMMeq/7

Comment: This allows adjacent plusses and dots.

Comment: What you mean? Did you checked the sandbox?

Comment: The comment obviously pertains to the version as of when I left the comment.